# Removing long words regex

Tags: php, regex

I would like to how can I remove long word from a string. Words greater than length n.

I tried the following:

```
//remove words which have more than 5 characters from string
$s = 'abba bbbbbbbbbbbb 1234567 zxcee ytytytytytytytyt zczc xyz';
echo preg_replace("~\s(.{5,})\s~isU", " ", $s);
```

Gives the Output (which is incorrect):

```
abba 1234567 ytytytytytytytyt zczc xyz
```

Comment: @stereofrog - yes i should have defined that better, it can be a string of any characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
//remove words which have more than 5 characters from string
$s = 'abba bbbbbbbbbbbb 1234567 zxcee ytytytytytytytyt zczc xyz';

$patterns = array(
    'long_words' => '/[^\s]{5,}/',
    'multiple_spaces' => '/\s{2,}/'
);

$replacements = array(
    'long_words' => '',
    'multiple_spaces' => ' '
);
echo trim(preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $s));
?>
```

Output:

```
abba zczc xyz
```

---

**Update**, to address the issue you presented in the comments. You can do it like this:

```
<?php
//remove words which have more than 5 characters from string
$s = '123&nbsp;ReallyLongStringComesHere&nbsp;123';

$patterns = array(
    'html_space' => '/&nbsp;/',
    'long_words' => '/[^\s]{5,}/',
    'multiple_spaces' => '/\s{2,}/'
);

$replacements = array(
    'html_space' => ' ',
    'long_words' => '',
    'multiple_spaces' => ' '
);
echo str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', trim(preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $s)));
?>
```

Output:

```
123&nbsp;123
```

Comment: nice, only one that takes care of urls also

Comment: @Imran Omar Bukhsh: Thanks! If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the tick below the vote count on the left side of my answer.

Comment: yes i do not mind doing that, but if you could just help further by also telling me how can I remove words starting and ending with the &nbsp;

Comment: @Imran Omar Bukhsh: They should be removed already, give me a sample string and tell me what should be the output, so I can test.

Comment: example: '123&nbsp;ReallyLongStringComesHere&nbsp;123'

Comment: hehe, smart, replace the html spaces with the usual spaces...thanx, let me just test it before i mark it

Comment: this won't remove the trailing space if the last word (but not the preceding) is too long (and the same is true for the very first word). I know, nobody cares... but possibly replacing original spaces with `&nbsp;` is really *ugly*.

Comment: Well it still converts `&nbsp;`s to spaces which is bad, but, again, I guess nobody cares.

Comment: @yi_H: Yes, it converts `&nbsp;` to space, removes long words, converts multiple spaces to single space, removes space from the start and end of string, then converts back space to `&nbsp;`. Now my question, why is it bad to replace `&nbsp;` with a space?

Comment: If you ask about why it doesn't do what it should, well if you start with a string like "abcdefg ab hijklmn cd opqrstuv" the resulting string will contain `&nbsp;`-s although the original didn't. If you ask in general why is it bad to replace them, well `&nbsp;` is a non-breakable space, has a different meaning in an HTML document.

Comment: @yi_H: The OP specifically asked for the `&nbsp;` to be there, because the string is being used in HTML or URL, read a few comments above.

Comment: as far as I understand he asked that it should treat `&nbsp;` as whitespace. I don't see that he asked for removal or conversion.

Answer (score 5):

Use this regex: `\b\w{5,}\b`. It will match long words.

1. `\b` - word boundary
2. `\w{5,}` - alphanumeric `5` or more repetitions
3. `\b` - word boundary

Comment: example ' testing 123 htttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744272/removing-long-words-regex/6744316#6744316  testing 123'; - it wont remove the url

Comment: @Imran, Try this: `\b\S{5,}\b`

Answer (score 1):

A better approach maybe to use regular string manipulation instead of a regex? A simple implode/explode and strlen will do nicely. Depending on the size of your string of course, but for your example it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're close:

```
preg_replace("~\w{5,}~", "", $s);
```

Working codepad example: http://codepad.org/c5AN1E6M

Also, you'll want to collapse multiple spaces into one:

```
preg_replace("~ +~", " ", $s);
```

[Example for this one](http://codepad.org/RtIlWaIe)

Answer (score 0):

Add the global modifier `g` or use `preg_match_all()`.

Answer (score 0):

Summary:

- any answer starting or ending with `\s` will fail to remove words at the beginning and the end of string (and you should use a test string which fails with these!)
- `\b` doesn't fail like that but it won't remove whitespaces. you can combine that  what a suggested double-space remover but that won't preserve original duplicated whitespaces (this may not be a problem).
- explode+implode has a nice property that it preserves duplicated whitespaces but you have to do it for every whitespace character.
- an alternative for whitespace-preserving (which I haven't seen here) is to use two patterns, one starting with `\b` ending with `\s` and another one starting with `\s` and ending with `$`.

Comment: Can anyone find the bug here? ;)

Comment: no bug, just an incomplete solution, check the answer marked as the correct one

Comment: there's a bug, I can assure you. regarding the other answer: well you haven't specified that in the question, you asked about that after my answer. btw if you don't want to preserve whitespaces that solution is fine.